# How to convert an Image to OLE object in VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have done adding the Picture to the database using the automated insertion provided by the visual studio.
Now I have written my own insert query and trying to add the image like

```
INSERT INTO Std_Table Std_Picture Values(StdPicBox.ImageLocation)
```

I know that the above statement is wrong because adding Image location to **OLE object** is making no sense. So what I would like to have the code for converting The picture to OLEobject for proper storing and retreiving in the database.

Comment: We cant possibly tell you what is wrong with your code without seeing...your code.  See [Ask]

Comment: Currently we are working in vb.net not in c# so kindly tell us in vb.net how to convert an image to OLE object in vb.net